# Generic matrix: how to pass a type in a function argument

Tags: c, generics, matrix

I created a generic matrix structure like this:

```
typedef struct mat_t {
  /**
   * \brief matrix structure
   */
  unsigned int c, l;
  void **matrice;
}* mat;
```

My problem is to learn how to allocate memory for the matrix because it can contain complex numbers, float numbers or others...
Thus, I want to know how to pass a type to my function argument for allocation memory.

```
mat allocate_mat(unsigned int l, unsigned int c, **<type>** )
```

Maybe, should I use a define macro for this function?

Comment: Why not just passing the size of the type ? Like, `mat allocate_mat(unsigned int l, unsigned int c, unsigned int size)` and then call it this way : `allocate_mat(10,5,sizeof(float))`

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: weird variable names. What are `l` and `c` supposed to mean? "Lines", "count"? There is nothing in C preventing you from using full words as variable names...

Problem 2: you are most likely using a false would-be 2D array, with pointer-to-pointer notation, which results in a heap fragmentation fiasco. Not only is it slow and leads to heap fragmentation, it also can't be used with fundamental C functions like memset(), memcpy(). Allocate a true 2D array instead, in adjacent memory.

Problem 3: Why do you have `* mat` at the end of the struct typedef? It doesn't make any sense.

Here is a basic implementation of a dynamic matrix, using generic C programming:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct mat_t
{
  void** data;
  size_t row_n;
  size_t col_n;
  size_t obj_size;
} matrix_t;


bool matrix_init (matrix_t* mat, 
                  size_t    row_n, 
                  size_t    col_n,
                  size_t    obj_size)
{
  mat->row_n = row_n;
  mat->col_n = col_n;
  mat->obj_size = obj_size;

  mat->data = calloc(row_n * col_n, obj_size);

  return mat->data != NULL;
}


void matrix_free (matrix_t* mat)
{
  free(mat);
}


void matrix_set (matrix_t* mat,
                 size_t    x,
                 size_t    y,
                 void*     val)
{
  size_t data_offset = y * mat->row_n * mat->obj_size + 
                       x * mat->obj_size;

  memcpy (mat->data + data_offset,
          val,
          mat->obj_size);
}


void* matrix_get (const matrix_t* mat,
                  size_t x,
                  size_t y)
{
  size_t data_offset = y * mat->row_n * mat->obj_size + 
                       x * mat->obj_size;

  return mat->data + data_offset;
}


int main()
{
  matrix_t mat;
  const int ROWS=3;
  const int COLS=2;

  // allocate memory
  matrix_init(&mat, ROWS, COLS, sizeof(int));


  // fill memory with data 1,2,3...
  int count =0;
  for(int row=0; row<ROWS; row++)
  {
    for(int col=0; col<COLS; col++)
    {
      count++;
      matrix_set (&mat, row, col, &count);
    }
  }

  // print the matrix
  for(int row=0; row<ROWS; row++)
  {
    printf("[ ");
    for(int col=0; col<COLS; col++)
    {
      printf("%d ", *(int*)matrix_get(&mat, row, col));
    }
    printf("]\n");
  }

  matrix_free(&mat);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't make any sense"? That's the essence of a typedef! `typedef struct mat_t {/*matrix*/ unsigned int c, l; void **matrice} * mat;` says, "here is what a `struct mat_t` looks like, now create type `mat`, which will be a pointer-to-struct of type `struct mat_t`."

Comment: @ElchononEdelson What I mean is, it doesn't make any sense to hide a pointer declaration behind a typedef, particularly in this case. It only makes the code bug-prone and hard to read.

Comment: Ah. That was not in any way clear from the way you said it. Regardless, however, of your opinion that it makes the code bug-prone and hard to read, it seems to me to be a fairly common idiom.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Software bugs are also fairly common. There is so much bad programming practice that is commonly used, one could write whole books about it.

Comment: The pointer structure definition makes sense to my mind, but thanks for all your your advices !

Comment: @Lundin Can you explain why you are multiplying the x and y variables by obj_size?

Comment: @Lundin I thought using `void*` was evil

Comment: @MehdiCharife This is a 10 year old(!) answer and I have no idea what I was thinking when I posted it. I'm not going to muck around with very old posts like this - just assume it is possibly quite outdated by now and not necessarily best practice.

Comment: @Lundin I understand, but how would you go about implementing a generic matrix in C if asked now? What would you use if not the `void**` construct? Would you use preprocessor macros or create a `struct` for a generic type to represent an element of the matrix?

Comment: @MehdiCharife I would probably base it on `unsigned char` instead since that's more flexible and type-generic, and also likely to generate fast code. Likely no to macros, although they can be used with `_Generic` in order to create a template-like interface where only a fixed number of types are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe, should I use a define macro for this function ?

Yes, you can define a macro to take a type in the last parameter, and call the real function which takes a size in the last parameter.

```
#define allocate_mat(MAT_L, MAT_C, MAT_TYPE) allocate_mat_sz(MAT_L, MAT_C, sizeof(MAT_TYPE))
mat allocate_mat_sz (unsigned l, unsigned c, size_t size);
```

Comment: I am constantly amazed by the intolerance towards a different way of doing things. It is so uninspiring.

Comment: It's certainly lame that you got a downvote without explanation.  Perhaps because you essentially change the language, e.g. `allocate_mat(2,3,float);` which compiles only with your macro.  Interesting approach though.

Comment: @MattPhillips: Well, it's not like there isn't a precedent in the C Standard itself. `va_arg()` comes to mind.

Comment: @Jens: except that the second line is the function prototype for `allocate_mat_sz()`, while the macro is for `allocate_mat()`, which expands into a call to the prototyped function.

Comment: Ha, I've seen `va_*` constructions but never used them, TIL +1.

Comment: @user315052 I was confused by the naming. I should seriously practice reading. :-)

Comment: Other generic functions in the C standard, such as memcpy, malloc, bsearch, qsort etc etc takes the size in bytes as parameters, rather than the type name. Why do you need a macro to help the programmer with typing out sizeof? I think the average C programmer is competent enough to do that without the aid of obscure macros...

Comment: @Lundin: I think the real question should be: Is the intention of the code clear? I am certain the same average C programmer would not be confused when reading a line of code that used that macro.

Comment: @user315052 If he isn't confused over sizeof and he isn't confused over the macro syntax, then what is the macro good for? I see no obvious advantage of `my_float = allocate(2,3, float)` versus `my_float = allocate(2,3,sizeof(my_float))`, except maybe better type safety in the latter case.

Comment: @Lundin: The obvious advantage in the context of this question is that it actually does what the asker asked about. I am simply answering the question as asked. The question was relatively simple, the answer is correspondingly simple. AnatolyS already answers the question the other way, so this is an alternative, that answers the question equally clearly by your admission, and does the requested action by taking a type as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass size of matrix element:

```
mat allocate_mat(unsigned int l, unsigned int c, unsigned int size_of_matrix_element )
```

Comment: Yes but I need two malloc for my matrix. So, I need two sizeof(), one for element pointer and one for element. How can I deal with it if I just pass size of matrix element ?

Comment: @user2412542 All pointers have the same size; e.g. `sizeof(void*)` will tell you what it is.

Comment: @MattPhillips Ok, I thought to make a malloc with a sizeof(void *) would be a mistake, but it seems good ! Thks

Comment: You can allocate memory for your matrix using linear representation of multi dimensional array: void *matrix = malloc(row_count*column_column*size_of_element); after that you can addresses any element of your matrix: ((yourtype*)&matrix[row*column_count+column])